# HBase java.io.EOFException when put record by java client

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Java client can't put record,but it's normal to create/drop table.
All operations pass in shell.

Hadoop version:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0
HBase version:0.94.6-cdh4.5.0

Exception:

```
2014-04-25 11:38:26,147 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil] - hconnection-0x2459162dfda0010 Retrieved 28 byte(s) of data from znode /hbase/root-region-server and set watcher; hadoop02,60020,1398304936512
2014-04-25 11:38:26,147 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation] - Looked up root region location, connection=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@6fac9964; serverName=hadoop02,60020,1398304936512
2014-04-25 11:38:26,148 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - Connecting to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$ConnectionId@d2476a75
2014-04-25 11:38:26,148 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - IPC Client (133764711) connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020 from hadoop@EXAMPLE.COM sending #0
2014-04-25 11:38:26,149 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - IPC Client (133764711) connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020 from hadoop@EXAMPLE.COM: starting, having connections 1
2014-04-25 11:38:26,149 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - closing ipc connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020: null
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.receiveResponse(HBaseClient.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.run(HBaseClient.java:586)
2014-04-25 11:38:26,151 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - IPC Client (133764711) connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020 from hadoop@EXAMPLE.COM: closed
2014-04-25 11:38:26,151 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - IPC Client (133764711) connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020 from hadoop@EXAMPLE.COM: stopped, remaining connections 0
2014-04-25 11:38:27,152 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - Connecting to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$ConnectionId@4724bb67
2014-04-25 11:38:27,152 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - IPC Client (133764711) connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020 from hadoop@EXAMPLE.COM sending #1
2014-04-25 11:38:27,152 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - IPC Client (133764711) connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020 from hadoop@EXAMPLE.COM: starting, having connections 1
2014-04-25 11:38:27,153 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - closing ipc connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020: null
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.receiveResponse(HBaseClient.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.run(HBaseClient.java:586)
2014-04-25 11:38:27,153 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - IPC Client (133764711) connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020 from hadoop@EXAMPLE.COM: closed
2014-04-25 11:38:27,153 DEBUG [org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient] - IPC Client (133764711) connection to hadoop02/10.80.11.236:60020 from hadoop@EXAMPLE.COM: stopped, remaining connections 0
```

Thanks a lot.